# How to working Searching sebset algorithm

Tags: bit-manipulation, subset

When i was studying for problem solving, i met a monster

```
int b = 0;
int x = (1<<6)|(1<<5)|(1<<2)
do {
// process subset
} while((b=(b-x)&x));
```

I know the result but I can't understand this code.

What is "(b-x)&b" mean?

How did you make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a trick to increment an integer but using only a subset of the bits, namely `x`.

> What is "(b-x)&b" mean?

This is wrong, it's `(b - x) & x`.

The key to this trick is the subtraction, so make sure you understand what subtraction does. For example one way to think about it is, from lsb-to-msb, subtract the i-th bit of the subtrahend and the borrow from the last iteration from the i-th bit of the minuend, giving the i-th bit of the difference and the next borrow.

The forms of `x` and `b` are such that `b` can only have bits set that are also set in `x`, that's true at the start and it stays true thanks to `& x`.

Giving that `x` and `b` are in those forms, then we know that whenever a borrow is generated, it "flows up" through the bits at least until the position of the next set bit in `x` (there can be no set bits in `b` between the origin of the borrow and there, because a bit in `b` can only be set if it is set in `x`). So the borrow will make it all the way to the next bit that is supposed to be affected, and "skip" all the extra zeroes in between.

The extra zeroes that are borrowed through are also turned into ones by the subtraction, but the `& x` turns all those to zero again.

An alternative way to write this, which may be easier to think about, is `((b | ~x) + 1) & x`. Same principle but with addition: the "bits to ignore" are set by `| ~x`, then the `+1` can carry through the "gaps" when necessary. This way of doing it costs extra operations because it needs the gaps to be filled with ones instead of with zeroes, which the subtraction-based trick works directly on the desired format.